# What's with the Jobs tab?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I see that on math.SE and meta there's a new tab labeled 'Jobs', but it just directs to "Page Not Found".  What's that for?  Is there a new feature that's not working correctly yet?

Comment: Will there be a 'Wozniak' tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fresh evidence that people should not be deploying updates on Friday afternoons.

The tab was added to Stack Overflow as a way to tie SO Careers with the Q&A site. Its presence on all other sites is surely a bug. Expect the Jobs to disappear shortly.

A more thorough explanation just came by way of developer Adam Lear, who retweeted [this](https://twitter.com/JonathanDeMoor/status/676027065171316737/video/1) a moment ago.